# Passing array of string as an argument in Hive Query (HQL)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

I am working on HQL where I need to pass an array of strings as an argument:

```
select * from table_1 where id not in ('${idListToFilter}')
```

I want to pass `idListToFilter` as an argument in Hive query. Tried using values like

```
idListToFilter="'1','2','3'"
```

but getting an exception:

> NoViableAltException(340@[319:1: constant : ( ( intervalLiteral )=> intervalLiteral | Number | dateLiteral | timestampLiteral | StringLiteral | stringLiteralSequence | IntegralLiteral | NumberLiteral | charSetStringLiteral | booleanValue | KW_NULL -> TOK_NULL );])

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IN clause requires a list or a column, not a comma-separated string. 
One way to do what you want is to `split` and `explode` a string, something like this:

```
WITH values AS (
  select explode(split('${hivevar:idListToFilter}',',')) val
)
SELECT * FROM table_1 t
WHERE t.id NOT IN (
  SELECT trim(x.val) from values x
);
```

... where `idListFilter` is passed into HQL as a simple comma-separated string, via

```
$ beeline --hivevar idListToFilter="id1,id2,id3" ...
```

Comment: tried this, but if idListToFilter has a space between the different ids, that will create an issue

Comment: There's always a `trim()` to remove unwanted spaces. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this from beeline:

my_sql.sql

```
select '${hivevar:my_val}';
```

command from beeline

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 --hivevar my_val=ARRAY['1','2','3'] -f my_sql.sql
```

output

```
+---------------+--+
|      _c0      |
+---------------+--+
| ARRAY[1,2,3]  |
+---------------+--+
```

or pass an string with comma separated values and then split the array

my_file.sql

```
select SPLIT('${hivevar:my_val}',',');
```

command from beeline

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 --hivevar my_val="rojo, amarillo, azul" -f my_sql.sql
```

ouput

```
+-------------------------------+--+
|              _c0              |
+-------------------------------+--+
| ["rojo"," amarillo"," azul"]  |
+-------------------------------+--+
```